# How can I get row data when clicking on it?

Tags: tabulator

How can I get row data when clicking on it? This is how I do it, but it doesn't work.

````
table.on("rowClick", function(e, row) {
    ```
    alert(row)
    ```
});
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getData()` method which will give you access to many properties like id etc. Something as follows.

```
table.on("rowClick", function(e, row) {
  alert(row.getData().id)
});
```